# rsyslogd: imjournal: fopen() failed for path: '/imjournal.state.tmp': Permission denied

Tags: linux, rsyslog, rsyslogd

I am having a Linux server with 128 GB RAM, 32 CPU and its running TIBCO EBX application. When I checked my server log file(/var/log/messages), it filled with below messages. Are these messages causing any memory leaks(https://github.com/rsyslog/rsyslog/issues/3301)? Continuously getting below messages will affect server performance degradation? How can I solve it.
The issue we are facing is our EBX process go into hang state and automatically restarted.

```
May 30 04:52:08 srsdc301236541 rsyslogd: imjournal: fopen() failed for path: '/imjournal.state.tmp': Permission denied [v8.24.0-41.el7_7.2 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2013 ]
May 30 04:52:10 srsdc301236541 rsyslogd: imjournal: fopen() failed for path: '/imjournal.state.tmp': Permission denied [v8.24.0-41.el7_7.2 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2013 ]
May 30 04:52:10 srsdc301236541 kernel: type=1400 audit(1685422329.500:50056): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=8211 comm="in:imjournal" name="/" dev="dm-5" ino=2 scontext=system_u:system_r:syslogd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:root_t:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
May 30 04:53:08 srsdc301236541 rsyslogd: imjournal: fopen() failed for path: '/imjournal.state.tmp': Permission denied [v8.24.0-41.el7_7.2 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2013 ]
May 30 04:53:08 srsdc301236541 kernel: type=1400 audit(1685422388.319:50057): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=8211 comm="in:imjournal" name="/" dev="dm-5" ino=2 scontext=system_u:system_r:syslogd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:root_t:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
May 30 04:53:10 srsdc301236541 kernel: type=1400 audit(1685422389.534:50058): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=8211 comm="in:imjournal" name="/" dev="dm-5" ino=2 scontext=system_u:system_r:syslogd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:root_t:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
May 30 04:53:10 srsdc301236541 rsyslogd: imjournal: fopen() failed for path: '/imjournal.state.tmp': Permission denied [v8.24.0-41.el7_7.2 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2013 ]
```

Comment: The path to the state file looks wrong. Check the rsyslog config has `$WorkDirectory /var/lib/rsyslog` and
`$IMJournalStateFile imjournal.state`, (or the equivalent
`global(workDirectory="/var/lib/rsyslog")` and `module(load="imjournal"
StateFile="imjournal.state")`. I don't think there should be a `/` at the
start of `StateFile=`.